# How numpy.tensordot command works?and what is the meaning of summing over axis in this command?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to understand how `numpy.tensordot` command works. I go through different questions posted on this forum related to this command. Moreover `axes (1,0)` indicate that `axes 1 in a` and `axes 0 in b` will be summed over. So I sum the terms along *axes 1 in a* and along *zero axis in b* and calculated answer manually but the result is different. May be my understanding about summed along a particular axis is wrong. Can someone please explain how we are getting final result in this following code?

```
a = numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
b = numpy.array([[0,5],[-1,20]])

c = numpy.tensordot(a,b,axes=(1,0))

print(c)
print("result")
[[-2 45]
[-4 95]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [432]: a=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]); b=np.array([[0,5],[-1,20]])                
In [433]: np.tensordot(a,b,axes=(1,0))                                          
Out[433]: 
array([[-2, 45],
       [-4, 95]])
```

The (1,0) means axis 1 of `a` and axis 0 of `b` are the sum-of-products axes.  That's just the normal `np.dot` pairing:

```
In [434]: np.dot(a,b)                                                           
Out[434]: 
array([[-2, 45],
       [-4, 95]])
```

I find the `einsum` notation to be clearer:

```
In [435]: np.einsum('ij,jk->ik',a,b)                                            
Out[435]: 
array([[-2, 45],
       [-4, 95]])
```

In any case this is matrix product we learned in school - run your finger across the rows of `a`, and the down the columns of `b`.

```
[[1*0+2*-1, 1*5+2*20], ...]
```

Yet another expression - expanding from the `einsum` one:

```
In [440]: (a[:,:,None]*b[None,:,:]).sum(axis=1)                                 
Out[440]: 
array([[-2, 45],
       [-4, 95]])
```

`tensordot` reshapes and transposes axes, aiming to reduce the problem to a simple call to `np.dot`.  It then reshapes/transposes back as needed.  The details depend on the `axes` parameters.  In your case no reshaping is needed, since your specification matches the default `dot` action.

A tuple axes parameter is relatively easy to explain.  There is also a scalar axis case (0,1,2 etc), that's a bit trickier.  I've explored that in another post.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain it for the case of third order tensor? axis zero and one are easy to handle but what about axis 2 ?

Comment: What about axis 2?  You'll have to set up a clearer example.